# React-Router - How to automatically pass a current param to a "<Link>"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using react-Router, I want the first token of my urls to be the language the site will use (english, french, spanish, etc.), for internationalisation purpose. For exemple :

```
http://example.com/#/en
http://example.com/#/en/help
```

or

```
http://example.com/#/fr
http://example.com/#/fr/help
```

My routes currently look something like this :

```
<Route path="/">
    <Route handler={App} path="/:lang/?">
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
        <DefaultRoute name="index" handler={Index} />
        <Route name="help" path="help" handler={Help} />
    </Route>

    /* add a default lang */
    <Redirect from="/" to="index" params={{lang: 'en'}} />
</Route>
```

You see the ":lang" parameter will always be there, in any route.

When I create a `<Link>` component, let's say from the "index" page to the "help" page, I currently do :

```
<Link to="help" params={this.props.params}>{t("header_menu_help")}</Link>
```

It seems I need to add `params={this.props.params}` (or `{...this.props}` or directly the "lang" param) or otherwise the router complains :

```
Invariant Violation: Missing "lang" parameter for path "/:lang/?/help"
```

But since all the routes below the "/:lang/" part will always have the same lang, is there a way to automatically pass that "lang" parameter without having to explicitly add it, when creating a Link?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a custom component that automatically sets the params... something like this:

```js
// LangLink component
var LangLink = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Link {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Link>;
  }
});

// App
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <LangLink to="path">My Link</LangLink>;
  }
});
```

Check out the last comment here to see how the the Link was "converted" into a Tab component.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me as is since I would have to pass the "lang" props everywhere. But I tweak your idea a little bit and found what I was looking for.  In the LangLink 's render() : `<Link params={{lang : config.currentLang()}} {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Link>`. Thanks for the help!